# What event to use to trigger insertion of JSON content into an existing HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, getjson

I'm building a proof of concept for my first responsive web-site with `JavaScript`, `JQuery`, and `Bootstrap`.  At this time I'm prototyping the front-end only.

I need to dynamically insert the content from a text file with `JSON` content (in a final application it will come from a server-side database) into my HTML.

I have the following structure of **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home Page</title>

        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>

       ...
       <ul class="list-unstyled" id="itemList">
           <!-- JQuery function will be called when DOM is ready -->
       </ul>
       ...

       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">/script>
       <script src="my.js"></script>
       <script>
            $( document ).ready("fillInData('text.json')");
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In **my.js** I have the following code:

```
function fillInData (dataFile) {
    // remove any existing content
    var ft = $('#itemList');
    ft.empty();

    // populate new stuff from a co-located JSON file
    var htmlString = "";
    $.getJSON(dataFile, function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
            htmlString += '<li>' + item.name + ...;
            ...
            htmlString += '</li>'
        });
    });
    ft.innerHTML = htmlString;
}
```

My problem is that it does not seem that `fillInData` functioned is called at all.

Since the `ready` event should not be fired before the entire `body` is parsed, I do not believe that I placed the hook too far down.

I use `Chrome Dev Tools` for debugging.  I placed a breakpoint inside my JS function, expecting to go step-by-step from there, but the breakpoint was never reached.

Am I missing something obvious here? Could it be just a RTFM case?

Comment: Remove the double quotations from "fillInData('text.json')".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    fillInData('text.json');
});
```

passing a string to `$.ready()` doesn't really work

**EDIT:**

and fix your ajax

```
$.getJSON(dataFile, function(data) {
    var htmlString = "";

    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
        htmlString += '<li>' + item.name + ...;
        ...
        htmlString += '</li>'
    });

    ft.html(htmlString); // it's a jQuery object, and it's async

});
```

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully that's it. Will test and report back.

Comment: @PM77-1 - It solves the issue you're asking about, it does not solve the fact that you're off base with your ajax function, which is **asynchronous**, so what you're doing will never work.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Because DOM tree is already being parsed at the time I do it?  What is the proper way to do it anyway?

Comment: @PM77-1 - I've added that to the answer. It doesn't work because $.getJSON is ajax, and ajax is **Asynchronous Javascript And XML**, so when you're setting the HTML, the data from the ajax call isn't there yet, it's working in the background,

Comment: May is ask how it **should** be done instead?  My debugging does show that `htmlString` is still empty at the time I'm about to use its value.

Comment: @PM77-1 - Read the answer above ?

Comment: **Finally** I understood all the changes you made. It's working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

will this hit your breakpoint?

`$(document).ready(function(){
fillInData('text.json');
});`